# Nginx and Gunicorn WSGI Variables

Tags: python, nginx, gunicorn, wsgi

I'm testing Gunicorn as an alternative to uWSGI. An Nginx reverse-proxy is set up in front of the Gunicorn instance. A consequence of not using uWSGI is I have to resort to using Nginx's `proxy_pass` instead of `uwsgi_pass`. With `uwsgi_pass` I could use `uwsgi_param` to overwrite the `PATH_INFO` and `SCRIPT_NAME` WSGI variables. `proxy_pass` has no equivalent directive. How do you set these WSGI variables for `proxy_pass` for a WSGI compliant application server such as Gunicorn?

Comment: I *think* you may be looking for `proxy_set_header` which is touched on [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59597317/difference-between-uwsgi-param-and-proxy-set-header)... specifically: `With proxy_pass - request is forwarded as HTTP request to upstream server. And with proxy_set_header headers and their value to be passed can be set.`
`With uwsgi_pass request is forwarded via uwsgi binary protocol. It is not http, it has no 'headers', instead it has parameters to be passed by uwsgi_param (if parameter name is prefixed with HTTP_ - it is available as a header in wsgi app).`

Comment: @v25 I'm not sure if `proxy_set_header` is a proper replacement. According to [PEP 3333](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/#environ-variables), HTTP headers will be set as WSGI variables named `HTTP_...`. I'm looking to set specially `SCRIPT_NAME` and possibly `PATH_INFO`. I suppose Gunicorn might support headers such as `X-WSGI-...` to set those but I haven't found documentation relating to this detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gunicorn [documentation](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-set-script-name) suggests that you can specify `SCRIPT_NAME` through an HTTP header without any further explanation. Digging through the source code revealed that it accepts a non-standard header actually named `SCRIPT_NAME`. The following can be used to set `SCRIPT_NAME` for Gunicorn:

```
proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /myapp;
```

`PATH_INFO` cannot be set. However, in my case `PATH_INFO` does not need to be set for Gunicorn because it automatically strips the `SCRIPT_NAME` prefix from `PATH_INFO`. With uWSGI I had to overwrite `PATH_INFO` to strip the `SCRIPT_NAME` prefix.